# How to add a 'Record Deleted' message in this code?

Tags: asp.net

I want to add a Record Delete Message when the Delete button is selected.  The message would appear for 5 seconds, then disappear.  Here's the code:

```
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ScheduleId">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SDate" HeaderText="SDate" SortExpression="SDate" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="STime" HeaderText="STime" SortExpression="STime" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SNoPlaces" HeaderText="SNoPlaces" 
                        SortExpression="SNoPlaces" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ScheduleId" HeaderText="ScheduleId" 
                        InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ScheduleId" Visible="false" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="STourId" HeaderText="STourId" SortExpression="STourId" Visible="false" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TName" HeaderText="Tour Name" SortExpression="TName" /> 
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ChinatowndbConnString %>" 
                DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Schedule WHERE (ScheduleId = @ScheduleId)" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT SDate, STime, SNoPlaces, ScheduleId, STourId, TName FROM Schedule INNER JOIN Tour ON Schedule.STourId = Tour.TourId">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="ScheduleId" />
                </DeleteParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Regards
Tea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this gridview event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleted(object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
{
    LabelMsg.Text = "Record Deleted";
}
```

I would use jQuery to always Fadeout the LabelMsg element on $(document).ready().  So no matter what you put in it, from the server side, it will fade out in the time you decide.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can accomplish this naively as part of a `GridView` but you can wire up the `RowDeleted` event to inject some JavaScript using the `ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` method.

I would suggest using toastr to display your actual message and it can be added to your project with its associated nuget package.

[RowDeleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdeleted.aspx)

[RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr)